# PHP MySQL хранение реквестов

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Подскажите, в очень нагруженных проектах бывают таблицы реквестов сплошняком, или хранят только суммарную информацию?

Вопрос возник, так как появился проект на 300-500 тысяч реквестов в день. Сервер с медленным жестким диском (7200). И на таблице реквестов (InnoDb) начали раз в 3-4 часа появляться 5-10 медленных insert-тов по 20-30 секунд весящих.
Выкрутил все что можно в Mysql но все равно иногда эти inser-ты всплывают. В таблице id-первичный ключ, и еще один индекс по времени. Версия MySQl 5.6.

Таблица сейчас  содержит 5млн записей. Есть вариант либо не хранить вообще реквесты, а оставить только сессии, либо использовать тип таблиц Memory, и информацию по ночам сливать.

Comment: Для очень нагруженных проектов используют NoSQL базы данных к примеру MongoDB

Comment: Для всего проекта или только для реквестов? Регулярно слышу, что многие отказываются от NoSQL и возвращаются обратно на MySQL,

Comment: Ну понятное дело, потому что не понимают как с ним нужно правильно работать...

Comment: Facebook? вроде перешел...

Comment: Facebook, это вообще самая кривая соц сеть в мире, там даже есть кусок моего кода... дальше говорить не о чем, про Facebook ))))

Comment: SQL/NoSQL надо выбирать исходя из информации с которой работать, а не от нагруженности. А в вашем конкретном случае надо понять, зачем вообще используется в дальнейшем эта таблица реквестов. и можно действительно суммировать, если каких то сумм достаточно. или вообще пользоваться логами web-сервера, а не писать в БД или ... в общем можно придумать десяток способов, но выбор оптимального зависит от всех нюансов задачи

Comment: @Shnur Кстати, в каком виде вы бы предложили сохранять лог запросов в NoSQL, в той же Mongo ?

Comment: @yavafree И вы говорите что у вас до 500к реквестов в день и при этом в таблице всего 5кк записей, там информация за 10 дней что ли ?

Comment: И для чего используется индекс по дате ? Может он него можно отказаться, например храня в отдельной таблице раз в 10 минут сохраняемое значение id из основной таблицы и текущее время. Тогда на основе нее можно будет прикинуть примерный диапазон id необходимый для отбора по интервалу дат и в запросе указать этот диапазон id (что бы оптимизатор пошел по первичному ключу) и точный диапазон дат, для отсеивания лишних записей.

Comment: Что значит реквесты?

Comment: Реквесты - каждое обращение пользователя к ресурсу, - время, идентификатор объекта доступа, айди пользователя., айди сессии, айди строки таблици

Comment: 5 миллионов записей - так как пока настраиваю, регулярно стираю их.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вынести нагруженную часть в отдельную БД. Возможно, вместо InnoDb использовать MyIsam, InnoDb не очень быстро вставляет. Я бы рекомендовал не сразу писать в базу, а писать в какую-то очередь, тот же Redis или RabbitMQ или даже в поминутные лог файлы. А уже из очереди крон скриптом выбирать данные и вставлять их в БД.

Comment: Попробовал myisam - получилось не лучше, даже может хуже, так как видимо еще и лочится таблица для других потоков. И тогда один запрос вешает все. Применять очереди не хочется чтобы проект не уложнять.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что весь затык происходит в момент сбрасывания данных на диск, раз в сколько то секунд. Хочу попробовать увеличить размер innodb_log_file_size ,  чтобы сброс данных пореже происходил.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike - спасибо, решил не писать все реквесты. Этот кусок тянулся из старого проекта, значит пришло время его убрать.